# Halachot that require a Mesorah

Tags: halacha, tradition

What halachot require a mesorah in order to be done correctly? (Meaning, reading them from a book is not sufficient)

Thanks

Comment: Which ones don't?

Comment: @DoubleAA Avraham managed to do אנכי ה' without one

Comment: @DoubleAA reading and following a certain halacha in the Shulchan Aruch or Rambam does not.

Comment: @Yishaq Doing it right certainly does. You can read and guess all you want.

Comment: Mareot in hilchot niddah

Comment: Shechita, nikur, milah, safrus, to name a few

Comment: Having a mesorah and reading from a book are not incompatible. I suggest you edit your question.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is your own misunderstanding of the goals of their works and not congruent with the opinions of the authors of both the Mishneh Torah or Shulchan Aruch - as can be seen from their introductions to their own works.

Comment: @DoubleAA When the brisker Rav or Rav Elayishiv make a diyuk in their works, I guarantee you that they are not doing it from a mesorah. (And please don't start with an authority fallacy)

Comment: @N.T. My question is geared specifically to those that can not be learned from a book.

Comment: @Chatzkel can you provide a source for any of those? Thanks

Comment: @kouty Most rabbis do not require a mesorah for mearot, since we are metameh and shade of red.

Comment: You should just ask that without reference to mesorah, then.

Comment: @Yishaq but u need a mesorah for what's considered red.

Comment: @Shlomy, as mentioned above, nowadays that we do not differentiate between the different shades of red as they did during the time of Chazal, most poskim believe you do not need a mesorah. Rav M. Feinstein was one of the few that held a shimush is required. But Rav Elyashiv and R S Zalman Aurebach held that no mesorah is required

Answer (score 1):

Shechita and Bedika of the lungs require a ksav Kabbalah from a Rav as per a cheirem instituted in the times of the Rishonim. See [Simla Chadasha 1:5](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=10)

Regarding Nikkur the Rema [YD 64:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.64.7?lang=bi)  and [65:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.65.8?lang=bi) states clearly that it cannot be learned from a sefer and must be done with apprenticeship

> הגה וסדר ניקור אלו החלבים צריך ראיה מן הבקי בניקור ואי אפשר לבאר היטב בספר

> ואין ללמוד סדר הניקור רק במראית העין מן המומחה הבקי בניקורו ד"ע

Kashrus of some birds and animals are reliant solely on Mesorah (YD 80-82)

A sofer and Mohel traditionally apprenticed before embarking on their own.

I’m sure there’s additional examples, anyone can feel free to add.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would love to see if anyone can extended this list.